# In Vim, add mouse click movement to the jump list

Tags: vim

In vim, when I use `set mouse=a` and I click somewhere, that movement is not added to the jump list.

Is there a way to enable this? Or use a plugin or a function?

Comment: Only jumps are added to the jump list. If you want your movements to be added to the jump list, use jumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enhance the mouse command to set a jump:

```
" <LeftMouse>       Add original position (from before the mouse jump) to
"                   the jump list.
nnoremap <LeftMouse> m'<LeftMouse>
```